# Adding vendor prefixes with LESS mixin

Tags: less, mixins, less-mixins

I'm getting a Syntax Error for this mix-in:

```
.vendors(@statement){
  @statement;
  -moz-@statement;
  -webkit-@statement;
}
```

Any way to do this, or do mixin variables have to be on the right side of a `:`?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920935/less-css-escape-entire-css-rule-with-different-prefixes/14943680#14943680) for LESS prefixing shows why you might not want to do this, and how pattern matching in LESS can be beneficial in prefixing.

Answer (score 5):

Since Less v2 you can use the [autoprefix plugin](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) to prefix your properties, which seems to be a better alternative. The autoprefix plugin add browser prefixes leveraging the [autoprefixer postprocessor](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer). For client side compiling (in the browser) you can use [-prefixfree](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree).

As already mentioned by @ScottS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920935/less-css-escape-entire-css-rule-with-different-prefixes/14943680#14943680) you can use variable interpolation in selectors since Less v1.6, which enables you to do:

```
.prefix(@property, @value)
{
    -webkit-@{property}:@value;
    @{property}:@value;
}
selector {
    .prefix(property,value);
}
```

outputs:

```
selector {
  -webkit-property: value;
  property: value;
}
```

You should also read: [Am I overcomplicating my LESS for vendor prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873745/am-i-overcomplicating-my-less-for-vendor-prefixes/26737212)

Answer (score 1):

That's a lame answer, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It's a very good question because that is possible in SASS and I am trying to mimmic that with Less ass well And I couldn't find any solution yet. Because I am as lame as anyone who know where the question came from.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that, but there are workarounds. If it worked, I think it would be something like this:

```
.vendors(@prop, @val){
  ~"-webkit-@{prop}:@{val}";
}
```

Note: this doesn't work.

Here's a very long discussion on the topic: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/698

You might be able to make use of this library: [less-properties](https://github.com/borodean/less-properties)